# Combining my tokenizer with synonym token filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I wrote my own tokenizer which splits the text on ' ' (space) and if I have Specific pre-defined phrases, they don't split. For example 'meat free' is a phrase and it won't be split.
So my tokenizer works well but when I use it in an analyzer in combination with synonym token filter it does not replace 'meat free' with its synonyms.

Do I have a way to make it work without re-writing my own synonym token filter?

**This is how I set my anlyzer:**

```
 "settings": {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : { 
                "analyzer" : {
                    "my_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "phrase_tokenizer",
                        "filter" : ["lowercase", "synonym"]
                    }
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "synonyms" : [
                            "meat free=> vegan, vegetarian, veggie"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

**This is how I test it:**

```
GET /my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&text=try try meat free try try
```

Result tokens are: `[try,try,meat free,try,try]`

I expect to get:  `[try,try,vegan,vegetarian,veggiee,try,try]`

Comment: Provide the full definition of `phrase_tokenizer` as well.

Comment: I uploaded it to: 
https://github.com/AdiGabaie/phrase-tokenizer

@AndreiStefan

Comment: You know that 0.90 version of ES is extremely old, right?.

Comment: I'm using 1.5.2.
Where did you see 0.9?

Comment: In your plugin code. You build the plugin with a dependency on ES 0.90.

Comment: I fixed it in the pom.xml file.
Did you mean there or somewhere else?

Comment: No, just the pom.xml.

Comment: Well, any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: No idea so far, but I discovered that, if it goes through the `lowercase` filter, it works. Meaning, try `GET /my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&text=try try mEAt free try try`.

Comment: I already saw it.. It is because my tokenizer code is not case sensitive and therefore it does split 'meat free' to two different tokens (as  if I used the standart tokenizer) and in this case the synonym mechanism works fine (it knows to replace [meat, free] tokens to vegan, vegetarian etc.)

Comment: Oh, I see now. Missed that. May I ask why do you need this type of analyzer? Wouldn't shingles do it for you?

Comment: *GET test_phrase/_analyze?tokenizer=phrase_tokenizer&text=meat free*  returns two tokens it only treats  *meat free*  as a phrase if it is inbetween a text.  Is that expected ?

Comment: My purpose is to not get 'meat' results when I search 'meat free'. I want 'meat free' to be treated as one term...

Comment: ooh thanks @keety
I didn't notice before. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Using shingles you can get terms that are made of two or more words. Take a look at this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html